# Certificados SSL y envío de JSON POST desde Java

Tags: java, java-ee, ssl, certificado-ssl

estoy desarrollando un servicio que debe enviar y recibir datos en formato JSON a un url externo que no controlo, que tiene un certificado SSL virtual. Por razones de privacidad/confidencialidad no puedo compartir muchos más detalles.

Mi problema es que por medi de aplicaciones como Postman y SopaUI puedo acceder y consumir el servicio y obtener la respuesta, pero desde Java es otra historia, se muestra la siguiente excepción:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Mi pregunta es, debería obtener algún tipo de llave privada de los desarrollodares del servicio externo o es algo que yo estoy haciendo mal.

P.D: Herramientas como InstallCert.Java no han ayudado a obtener el certificado del url mencionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como creo que esto te viene muy de nuevo, voy a dar un repaso general al sistema. Los comandos específicos son fáciles de buscar según sea tu caso.

En resumidas cuentas, otras aplicaciones usan los almacenes de certificados del sistema para verificar la identidad de las máquinas con las que comentan, pero Java tiene su propio sistema de almacenes.

No necesitas ninguna clave privada (salvo que el servidor de destino tenga habilitada la autenticación de clientes por certificado, que no suele ser el caso).

Abre en el navegador la URL donde te conectas, en la línea de la URL te mostrará la información de certificados (solo verás la parte pública).

El certificado se presenta como una cadena: en última instancia está el certificado del servidor, y antes están los certificados de las CAs que avalan ese certificado (opcional). Puedes usar cualquiera de ellos; la diferencia es que si usas un certificado de CA acabarás confiando en todos los certificados que esta CA avale.

Con el explorador, importas ese certificado y lo exportas a un fichero como .DER.

Ahora hay que poner el certificado en un *truststore* de Java; tienes dos opciones:

- Importar el certificado en el *truststore* por defecto del JDK/JRE, que está en `[JRE_HOME]/lib/security/cacerts` o `[JDK_HOME]/jre/lib/security/cacerts`. Afectará a todas las invocaciones a la JVM que no especifiquen su propio *truststore*.
- Crear un *truststore* independiente para tu aplicación. En el momento de invocar a tu aplicación, lo más normal es indicarlo mediante `-Djavax.net.ssl.truststore=[ruta truststore] -Djavax.net.ssl.truststorePassword=[contraseña]`.

Sea como sea, tienes que manipular el *truststore* con la herramienta `keytool`, que está en `[JDK_HOME]/bin/keytool` o `[JRE_HOME]/bin/keytool`, con algo similar a:

```
keytool -import -certfile=[tu fichero DER] -keystore=[ruta al truststore] -alias=[etiqueta para el certificado que importas, solo para visualizar]
```

y seguir las instrucciones (la contraseña por defecto del *truststore* del sistema es `changeit`).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta,¿y una vez que haga esto puedo tratar la interacción como si fuese por http sencillo o debo tratarla de alguna otra manera?

Comment: Normalmente los detalles de como se establecen las conexiones se gestiona directamente por las clases del JDK; tú simplemente obtienes una conexión y los detalles de como funciona por debajo te dan igual.

Answer (score 0):

por lo general se deshabilita el control SSL con este método que comparto más abajo.

```
   static public void doTrustToCertificates() throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                return;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
            if (!urlHostName.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getPeerHost())) {
                System.out.println("Warning: URL host '" + urlHostName + "' is different to SSLSession host '" + session.getPeerHost() + "'.");
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
}
```

Simplemente llamas a este método justo antes de realizar tu petición..!

Comment: Como comentas, este código simplemente ignora la validación del certificado y hace trivial la suplantación del servidor. Es por eso que está completamente desaconsejado.